# MPMoviePlayerViewController Support landscape iOS 4.3 to 6.1

Tags: iphone, landscape

I have one query regarding orientation and play video,

My application support portrait mode but when i start any video it will run only landscape mode then after when video have completed it automatically come portrait mode.

Below of the code I'm using

```
**MyMovieViewController.h** 

#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>


@interface MyMovieViewController : MPMoviePlayerViewController

@end

**MyMovieViewController.m**

@implementation MyMovieViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}

@end
```

But above of the code only working in iPhone 4.3 simulator and My application support 4.3 to 6.1.

So please can you help me out.

Comment: can you please tell what is actually you want?? you want only portrait mode or landscape mode???

Comment: Apple changed their rotation methods in iOS6. You may wish to check out the documentation to see the new API methods and implement them.

Comment: I want to movie play only landscape mode. and when movie finished view comes up original orientation like portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

These few methods only return YES when your device is in landscape. Then it wont support portrait mode.